# Использование кавычек при названии игрушки

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`1. Вязаная игрушка Тыква на Хэллоуин.`

`2. Вязаная игрушка «Тыква» на Хэллоуин.`

Comment: Я считаю, что кавычки нужны, если это название игрушки. Если имеется в виду, что это в виде тыквы, то строчная буква без кавычек. Отправил не в виде ответа, потому что не во всëм уверен.

Comment: Без кавычек принято писать латинские(английские) названия, все остальные в кавычках. То есть чай Липтон или Lipton, но шоколадка "Алёнка".

Comment: @Максим Если в виде тыквы, то без родового слова.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, так:

Вязаная игрушка **"Тыква"** на Хэллоуин.

Пример: В магазине можно купить вязаную игрушку **"Тыква"** на Хэллоуин.*

Это название игрушки, как и название шоколада "Аленка".

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148746/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Здесь название игрушки, потому что есть родовое слово. Кавычки не ставятся, когда что-то не настоящее. Очередной неправильный ответ...

Comment: Вам надо бы в чат..   И где ваш правильный ответ, опять написать забыли?

Comment: Посылать нельзя. Это не по правилам. На это можно тревогу ставить. Удаляйте. А вам надо бы исправить ответ. Очиститься чатом не получится.

Comment: Ставьте, какие проблемы?  Хотя проблемы, конечно, есть...)

Comment: Нельзя обзывать и посылать (никак!). Запомните!

Comment: А почему вы меня обзываете и опускаете, вам можно?

Comment: В чат посылать можно), приглашать точнее.

Comment: Ни разу вас здесь не обзывал! Опускаю ваши ответы (заслуженно), не вас :)

Comment: Я вас не посылал, но опускаю Заслуженно я вас не обзывал...

Comment: Вот, всё-таки можете себя перебороть и исправить.

Comment: Это вы для Буратино пишете? Наш разговор с ним  повлиял на мое решение, я просто ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО прочитала вопрос.

Comment: Нет, под вашим ответом же. Так вы неправильно отвечаете, потому что невнимательно читаете вопросы? :) Теперь понятно.

Comment: Rest already however...

Comment: Кстати, у вас прикольная логическая ошибка: получается, что шоколад "Аленка" тоже название игрушки (перечитайте).

Answer (score 1):

Вязаная тыква-игрушка на Хэллоуин.

Вязаная игрушечная тыква на праздник Хэллоуин.

Вязаная игрушка "Тыква на Хэллоуин"

Вязаная игрушка "Тыква-на-Хэллоуин".

Вязаная игрушка "Джек Леопольдович Тыквин" на празднование «кануна Всех Святых-с» (Ηalloween).

Comment: Должны безумно часто говорить, чтобы поросло дефисами. Только с именами такое возможно. "Вязаная игрушка-тыква" — каша.

Comment: @oleedd ну это название, назвать можно как угодно.

Comment: Разве что по приколу.

Comment: @oleedd ну хоть бы и так.

Comment: Буратино, у вас  в первом предложении тире или дефис? Вроде бы в названии дефис должен быть? (2) Вязаная игрушка-тыква – это корректно.

Comment: Буратино, у вас в предложении (1) тире или дефис? Вроде бы в названии дефис должен быть? (2) Вязаная игрушка-тыква – это корректно.

Comment: @Sharon тире у меня(, в первом

Comment: Но тогда это предложение, а не название. А все остальные названия.

Comment: Ну это название  - вязаная тыква, а дальше развернутое описание)

Comment: А как это может быть? Распространенный номинатив? Тогда это неправильная запись. Два сочетания в функции номинатива?

Comment: Шоколадка Аленка – это не просто вкусняшка, а необыкновенная сладость с многолетней историей, ибо этот молочный шоколад впервые увидел свет...

Comment: Это предложение, а Аленку в кавычки надо.

Comment: "Садовые гномики — небольшие фигурки в виде гномов в красных колпаках в различных позах" Педивикия, а то это с Вайлдберриз. Да, надо в кавычки Аленка, но может популярная типа шоколадка, и уже не надо. Хотя лучше надо.

Comment: Это тоже предложение, еще "это" можно добавить. Ничего не поняла, дайте ссылку на текст. Или лучше другой пример найдите.

Comment: @Sharon ну так кот Тыквин не дает подробного описания, что ему надо? В таком тексте-описании можно так писать или нет?

Comment: Описание не название. Номинатив  может быть только отдельным назывным предложением. Это все.  Тире, как мне думается, там не подойдет, а вот дефис да. Может, поменяете?  (В вопросе явное название.)  Кстати, у Розенталя подобные сочетание описаны, но там скорее дефис. Мне нравится так: Вязаная /тыква-игрушка/ на Хэллоуин.

Comment: @Sharon я второй удалил первый оставил с дефисом.

Comment: Да, все хорошо. Мой голос за вас.

Comment: @Sharon я бы за вас проголосовал, если бы вы поменяли Тыква на Аленка, потому что Аленка - это типа бренд, а Тыква как бренд не зарегистрируешь. О, еще идея появилась, нужно сделать ...